# How to increase int value with iteration while button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I'm working  with interface builder and now for finishing my very first app in xcode i have a question that i've not found a solution: How to increase an int value with an iteration while UIButton is pressed?

I've tried many solutions but in the best I've tried the iteration is infinite, for example I had two methods (Touch Up inside and Touch down) changing a bool value (if down bool=true and do the iteration; and if it's up bool=false and stop iteration).

Printing in console i have the same infinite result: "DOWN,TRUE"

So, how can i do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you like to achieve the counter automatically increases while you touch the button down?

Comment: Just looping forever will block the application. Look into timers.

Comment: Yes, I want that @holex

Comment: That's why i need to solve that @CrimsonChris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most-likely what is happening is that your loop is running on the UI thread. This means that the UI thread will be consumed by your loop until your loop finishes. The only way your loop will finish is if the `Touch Up Inside` method is fired. However, this event be created on the UI thread, which is currently busy with your loop.

You need to make use of background threads to increate your int value and print out to the console. That way, when the `Touch down` event is fired, the loop will be pushed to the background and the UI thread can continue processing future touch events.

A good resource is the [Thread management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) documentation on Apple's developer site:

Without worrying to much about concurrency programming, here is a simple example of something that will work.

```
int i = 0;
bool cancelLoop = NO;

- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    // Run in background so that the UI thread can continue to process touch events.
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startLoop) withObject:nil];
}

- (IBAction)touchUpInside:(id)sender {
    [self cancelLoop];
}

- (void)startLoop {
    cancelLoop = NO;
    while(!cancelLoop) {
        NSLog(@"%d", i++);
    }
}

- (void)cancelLoop {
    cancelLoop = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me read it. If I have questions about this could you help me??

Comment: Thanks! it works like a charm, I only add one more line of code to a perfect function:

- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    // Run in background so that the UI thread can continue to process touch events.
 
cancelLoop = false;

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startLoop) withObject:nil];
}



This will let use it repeated times until you reach a desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have action method then just declare the instance variable lets say

```
  @property(assign)NSUInteger i;
```

Now connect action method to UIButton  when it will click just iterate your i variable inside action method like that below:-

```
  _i++;
```

Comment: The incremental stuff is not a problem for me, my problem is how to do the loop when the button is pressed DOWN and when the push is released stop the loop.

Comment: The OP wants the value to increase constantly while the button is pressed. I think a solution using timers would be more appropriate.